# Paginator, Sort and Filter arent working for angular material project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

So I created a project on Angular CLI 7 and wanted to integrate angular material into it.

SO I have added modules for table pagination expansion filter sort etc.
Even though I have added them into the app modules file. The paginator sort and filter dont work. Please can you tell me what could be the problem here, been stuck for a while.

Please find below files:

material.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatCardModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule,
} from '@angular/material';

import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';

const modules = [
  MatCardModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatExpansionModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: modules,
  exports: modules,
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatCardModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule,
} from '@angular/material';

import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';

const modules = [
  MatCardModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatExpansionModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: modules,
  exports: modules,
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('void', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
      state('*', style({ height: '*', visibility: 'visible' })),
      transition('void <=> *', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  public projectsResponse = {}
  public projectsGL: Project[]

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['bob_id', 'name', 'pod', 'version', 'v_env'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Project> = new MatTableDataSource<Project>(this.projectsGL);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  isExpansionDetailRow = (index, row) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');

  constructor(private _projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._projectService.getProjects().subscribe(data => {
      this.projectsResponse = data;
      this.initializeProjects();
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Project>(this.projectsGL);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });

  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
}
initializeProjects()
/* code to populate projectGL */
```

Dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="projectsGL" matSort>

        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="bob_id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Bob Id </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.bob_id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="pod">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Pod </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.pod}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="version">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> version </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.version}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="v_env">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> v-env </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project"> {{project.v_env}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="project-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row" [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>

<ng-template #tpl let-project>
    <div class="mat-row detail-row" [@detailExpand] style="overflow: hidden">
        The Envirent for {{project.name}} is {{project.env}}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I seem to have added all the modules required still paginator, sort and filter isnt working.

Comment: I found the examples on the materials website to be incomplete. In this case if you look at the api https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource at a minimum I think `sortData` needs to be implemented. I plan on spending today working through the to find out what’s missing so if you find an answer please post. Including `BrowserAnimationsModule` is always one I miss.

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz example with this issue

Comment: @AndrewAllen I have already added BrowserAnimationsModule, havent found the solution yet

Comment: sorry @AmitBaranes do you want the complete project or just the  required files?

Comment: I have used this code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting

Comment: just the required files should be ok.

Comment: Found the solution, cursing myself after I found the mistake. <mat-table #table [dataSource]="projectsGL" matSort>  should have been <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

Comment: you put the same code in app.module.ts and material.module.ts?

Comment: No I add material modules in material.module then export it to app.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake,

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="projectsGL" matSort>
```

should have been

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```